# ARMA: selection of lagged variables

Tags: r, autoregressive, moving-average

In the `arma{tseries}` documentation in R, they select a few lagged variables:

```
library(tseries)
data(nino)
arma(nino3.4, lag=list(ar=c(1,3,7,10,12,13,16,17,19),ma=NULL))
```

http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tseries/functions/arma

What do I call such a model? Can I call it an ARMA(19,0) even if some lagged values in-between are ignored?

Comment: It might be helpful to complement the R code with mathematical notation of the model with restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is AR(19) model, not ARMA. It has constraints on some lags, i.e. $\phi_2=0$, $\phi_4=0$ etc.

$$y_i=c+\sum_{k=1}^{19}\phi_k y_{i-k}+\varepsilon_i$$

Generally, it's better to not have these constraints without a good reason. They tend to create weird effects.

Often, like with R, AR(P) processes are estimated by the same routine as ARMA or even ARIMA. MATLAB is the extreme case where they're all estimated by `arima' function. That's why some people would call this ARIMA or ARMA process, but I like to emphasize that it is AR(P). It's quite different from integrated processes, in that it is stationary. It's also quite different from ARMA processes, e.g. it can be estimated by OLS while ARMA process would require something like MLE.

Comment: Yes, the model can be called AR(19) or, indeed, autoregressive of order 19. Equally valid, though, are both ARMA(19,0) and ARIMA(19,0,0). I think it depends on context which one is most suitable. Obviously, it's always good to be explicit about notation, too; e.g. p=19, d=0, etc.

Comment: There is an _obvious error_, _which I assert_, in the subscript notation. My edit was refused(?), so I suggest here to make the necessary amendments to avoid confusion.

Comment: @GraemeWalsh, thanks for pointing to an error, fixed. AR(P) is most specific characterization, given that d=q=0 in this case.

Comment: One thing before I validate the answer: you say "it's better to not have these constraints without a good reason". When you do a summary on an arma model, R calculates for you the pvalue of the coefficient being relevant. I was always taught (in linear regressions) to remove the irrelevant variables. Should I always remove the "irrelevant" lagged variables in this kind of model? Would you? Is the negligible t-statistic a good reason to impose that constraint or should I just leave it there?

Comment: @RicardoCruz, I don't remove non-significant variables based solely on p-values even from OLS. In case of time series, it's even trickier. Your AR coefficients define frequency [spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model#Spectrum) of your process, seasonality etc. So, you've got to be careful with automatic lag-selections, they mess up your series

Answer (score 1):

I would call it ARMA(19, 0). The AR and MA terms are typically identified by the maximum lag, even if some values in between are ignored. If you think about the way the ARMA(p, q) model is specified

$$x_t = \sum_{i = 1}^p\alpha_i x_{t-i} + \sum_{j=1}^q\beta_j w_{t-j} + w_t$$

you can imagine some $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ values which happen to equal to zero.

Comment: I'd also add that 19 is a pretty high number of lag periods, but I realize you're using an example from the documentation

Comment: Or, as @Aksakal notes, AR(19)